# Regular expression how to use

Tags: regex

I am using a regular expression to validate an email address with example@gmail.com or example@google.net.

This is my regex:

```
/^([A-za-z0-9_\.-]+\@[\gmail\.-]+\.[com\.]{2,6})$/
```

However, it is wrong, somebody help me, thanks very much.

Comment: I have added the answer, check it out

Comment: You might consider splitting the string at the @ symbol, and having a whitelist of what is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will match both xxx@gmail.com and xxx@google.net

```regex
^[A-Za-z0-9_.\-]+@(?:gmail\.com|google\.net)$
```

You'll notice that the 2 domains are put in a non-capturing group, separated by a pipe (OR)

Do note also that something like `[com]` in a regex is not to match the word "com", but to match the characters "c","o","m".

Comment: [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926).

Answer (score 0):

Want something like

```
\w*[gmail]\.(?!com)
```